# data-ng-src with if condition

Tags: angularjs

I have an image that I display using this:

```
<img data-ng-src="data:image/jpg;base64,{{selectedReport.reportImage.imageFile.data}}"/>
```

The above data is fetched from my database.

When the user clicks edit record and selects a new image which is stored in variable imageFile, I want to show this `imageFile` instead of the record fetched.

How do I use an if condition with data-ng-src?
Individually these work, but i want to apply an if condition where I say, if ImageFile, then

```
data-ng-src="{{imageFile}}"
```

else

```
data-ng-src="data:image/jpg;base64,{{selectedReport.reportImage.imageFile.data}}"
```

I tried to do like this:

```
data-ng-src = {{imageFile}} and data-err-src = "data:image/jpg;base64,{{selectedReport.reportImage.imageFile.data}}"/>
```

But this doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should just use a function, declared in your controller to deal with the situation.

In your controller :

```
 $scope.getImage = function (){
    return $scope.imageFile || [your_default_image_file];
 }
```

In your HTML, something like :

```
<img data-ng-src="{{getImage()}}"/>
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: I ended up writing a function in controller and calling it when the image changed using ng-change.

Answer (score 3):

AngularJS views support binary operators

```
condition && true || false
```

So your `img` tag would look like this

```
<img data-ng-src="{{ imageFile != '' && imageFile || 'your-default-image' }}"/>
```

**Note** : You could use any condition to know if imageFile exists or has a value.

**Note 2** : the quotes (ie 'your-default-image') are important here. It won't work without quotes.

Comment: It doesn't help as I my default image is 64 bit encoded file and with the img tag below,  <img data-ng-src="{{ imageFile != '' && imageFile || 'data:image/jpg;base64,{{selectedReport.reportImage.imageFile.data}}' }}"/>  I get the error-  Lexer Error    https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$parse/lexerr?p0=Unterminated%20quote&p1=s%2032-98%20%5B%27data:image%2Fjpg;base64,%7B%7BselectedReport.reportImage.imageFile.data%5D&p2=imageFile%20!%3D%20%27%27%20%26%26%20imageFile%20%7C%7C%20%27data:image%2Fjpg;base64,%7B%7BselectedReport.reportImage.imageFile.data

Comment: since you already added the symbol {{ there is no need to use it again, in data:image/jpg;base64,{{selectedReport.reportImage.imageFil‌​e.data}}', it should look like data:image/jpg;base64,selectedReport.reportImage.imageFil‌​e.data'

Comment: try storing the content of an image inside a variable. the whole string